# How does elasticsearch find escaped character or reserved character correctly?

Tags: javascript, typescript, elasticsearch

Given that I have a string such as 'message-ID: 1394.00 This is Henry.Lin',
I want to use elasticsearch to find all the phrase or word contains '.'. In this case, 1394.00 and Henry.Lin are the words I am looking for. However, when I index my document with standard analyzer is not working. I understand that standard analyzer will escape such character. Therefore, I change the analyzer to ngram. Unfortunately, it is still not working. It would be great if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom character filter for dot. Replace "." with "dot". Just use the custom mapping like this:

```
"char_filter": {
"&_to_and": {
    "type":       "mapping",
    "mappings": [ ".=>dot"]
}}
```

Please check this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-analyzers.html#_creating_a_custom_analyzer) for more details.

***Now about, why ngram is not working ?***

The question is how are you using ngram - as a tokenizer or token filter with some other analyzer? What's the min_gram, max_gram size? Checkout this [example](https://qbox.io/blog/an-introduction-to-ngrams-in-elasticsearch) to clear the difference between two.

Also to understand more about how your data is getting indexes in elasticsearch and why not matching your query - try using [termvectors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html) api.

Finally I would not suggest you to use ngrams for solving this issue for following reasons - 1) n-grams are going to make your index larger , 2) They have totally different [use case](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html).

Comment: in that case I have to create filters for all the escaped characters?

Comment: I have tried your approach. However when it encounters document only contains one word such as `n/a` it fails.